# Output Of A Series

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java program to get the output of this series:

[image: series]

So I have done this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ICSE2007_Pg111 {

    public static void main() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter th elimit");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        double add = 0;
        double mult = 1;
        double divide = 0;
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int x = 1 ; x <= i; x++) {
                add += x;
                mult *= x;
            }

            divide = add / mult;
            total += divide;
        }
        System.out.println("The resultant sum = " + total);
    }
}
```

I think this code is correct. However, for the value of `n = 3` the correct output should be `2.916666666666666666`, but I am getting `2.25`.  If someone could please pin point the error.

Comment: you will get 2.916666666666666666 for n = 4(three iteration) and for n = 3 you will get 2.5

Comment: Just realized that sorry for the wrong information.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to reset `add` and `mult` before the inner loop :

```
   for(i = 2;i<=n;i++) {
        add = 0; 
        mult = 1;
        for(x =1 ;x<=i;x++)
        {
            add +=x;
            mult *= x;

        }
        ...
```

P.S. based on your image, for `n=3` you should get `2.5`.

Comment: @SamHat Look OK to me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in optimized way in one loop

```
float sum = 1;
float mul = 1;
float res = 0;
for(int i = 2;i<=n;i++) {
    sum = sum+i;
    mul = mul*i;
    res = res+(sum/mul);
}
```

Comment: This gives the wrong output when n =4 it gives 2.2083333 when its supposed to give 2.9